# Parse XML with VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse xml with VBA to obtain test results from an electrical test system.  This is an example of what the system is giving me:

```
<Reports>
<Report Type='UUT' Title='UUT Report' Link='-1-2013-11-20-10-2-46-867' UUTResult='Failed' StepCount='132'>
<Prop Name='UUT' Type='Obj' TypeName='UUT' Flags='0x0'>
    <Prop Name='SerialNumber' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
        <Value>02</Value>
    </Prop>
    <Prop Name='PartNumber' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
        <Value>1009433</Value>
    </Prop>
    <Prop Name='LotNumber' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
        <Value>1234567</Value>
    </Prop>
    <Prop Name='CriticalFailureStack' Type='Array' LBound='[0]' HBound='[1]' ElementType='Obj' Flags='0x0'>
        <ArrayElementPrototype Type='Obj' TypeName='NI_CriticalFailureStackEntry' Flags='0x0'>
            <Prop Name='StepName' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
                <Value></Value>
            </Prop>
            <Prop Name='SequenceName' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
                <Value></Value>
            </Prop>
            <Prop Name='SequenceFileName' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
                <Value></Value>
            </Prop>
            <Prop Name='ResultId' Type='Number' Flags='0x0'>
                <Value>0</Value>
            </Prop>
        </ArrayElementPrototype>
        <Value ID='[0]'>
            <Prop Type='Obj' TypeName='NI_CriticalFailureStackEntry' Flags='0x0'>
                <Prop Name='StepName' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
                    <Value>Brady Detection</Value>
                </Prop>
                <Prop Name='SequenceName' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
                    <Value>MainSequence</Value>
                </Prop>
                <Prop Name='SequenceFileName' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
                    <Value>1009450 AT ILR Final-test_app.seq</Value>
                </Prop>
                <Prop Name='ResultId' Type='Number' Flags='0x0'>
                    <Value>44</Value>
                </Prop>
            </Prop>
        </Value>
        <Value ID='[1]'>
            <Prop Type='Obj' TypeName='NI_CriticalFailureStackEntry' Flags='0x0'>
                <Prop Name='StepName' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
                    <Value>Number of Brady Beats</Value>
                </Prop>
                <Prop Name='SequenceName' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
                    <Value>Brady Detection</Value>
                </Prop>
                <Prop Name='SequenceFileName' Type='String' Flags='0x0'>
                    <Value>1009450 AT ILR Final-test_app.seq</Value>
                </Prop>
                <Prop Name='ResultId' Type='Number' Flags='0x0'>
                    <Value>49</Value>
                </Prop>
```

I'd like to pull out the Serial Number from `<prop name = 'serial number'>`, the test result from `<Report UUTResult = 'Failed'>`, and the device failures from `<Prop Type='Obj' TypeName='NI_CriticalFailureStackEntry' Flags='0x0'> <Value>Brady Detection</Value>`

I've never worked with XML before, but this is what I've gotten by reading this site so far:

```
Dim xml As New MSXML.DOMDocument60
Dim xReport As IXMLDOMElement
Dim result As String

xml.Load (filePath)
Set xReport = xml.SelectSingleNode("//Reports/Report/")
result = xReport.getAttribute("UUTResult")
```

When I run this, I get "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Automation Error Unspecified Error at Set xReport.

I also tried casting xml as new MSXML2.DOMDocument (rather than DOMDocument60) and then I get a type mismatch at the same line.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I seem to remember getting an error like that when the xml document was not well formed. Does it have the `xml` element at the very beginning?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729601/dynamically-search-for-data-in-an-xml-file-with-vba/19730346#19730346) may be helpful.

Comment: i started the code in my orig post at line 2. this is the first line: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:\Data\horizontal.xsl"?>

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to get your data without using `MSXML`

**TRIED AND TESTED**

If your format of the xml doesn't change than this will give you what you want.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sString  As String

    '~~> Replace your file here
    Open "C:\Sample.xml" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        If InStr(1, strData(i), "<Prop Name='SerialNumber'", vbTextCompare) Then
            sString = strData(i + 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If sString <> "" Then
        Debug.Print Trim(Replace(Replace(sString, "<Value>", ""), "</Value>", ""))
    End If
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]