# Excel VBA with XML V6.0 how do I get the data out of the file

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am an experienced VBA coder but brand spanking new to XML as you will see from this

I have the following xml file Fred.xml

```
-<Entry>

<ProposalTitle>this is the proposal title</ProposalTitle>

<ProposalOpportunity>this is the proposal opportunity </ProposalOpportunity>

<ProposalBenefits>this is the proposal benefits</ProposalBenefits>

<LocalChangeRepName>local rep name</LocalChangeRepName>

<LocalChangeRepNo>458645</LocalChangeRepPI>

<ProposerName>Proposer name</ProposerName>

<ProposersNo>123454</ProposersPI>

<ProposalDate>18/04/2014</ProposalDate>

</Entry>
```

and need to pull the data elements out of it into a set of viariables temp 1 to 8

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729601/dynamically-search-for-data-in-an-xml-file-with-vba/19730346#19730346) to parse xml.

Comment: `<LocalChangeRepNo>458645</LocalChangeRepPI> 
<ProposersNo>123454</ProposersPI>` should be `<LocalChangeRepNo>458645</LocalChangeRepNo> 
<ProposersNo>123454</ProposersNo>` to make it valid XML. I tested the code from above link & it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you how I do it:

Add a reference to the MS xml parser, under Tools > References

[image]

Then initialize and use the parser

```
Dim oDomDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument30
Set oDomDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument30
oDomDoc.async = False
oDomDoc.validateOnParse = False
If Not oDomDoc.Load(sFile) Then
    Set oDomDoc = Nothing
        '' Handle load failure 
End If
String sNodeValue as String
sNodeValue = oDomDoc.selectSingleNode("Entry/ProposalBenefits").Text
```

You'll have to do some homework on working with the DOM, but this should at least get you started.